# Update CiviCRM's copy of CKEditor using composer?

Tags: ckeditor, composer, security-advisory

According to https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2021-09-ckeditor-multiple-advisories a recommended mitigation is to replace /civicrm/bower_components/ckeditor/ with version 4.16.2 (it's currently 4.16.1 in older civi versions).

In a D8/9 install, that folder appears to get populated according to the composer.json in civicrm core, and this code https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/21108 shows how it was updated for the security release.

But, that change in the composer.json file is in a special section called "extra > downloads", and just updating the composer.json file and running composer update doesn't do anything (or at least, it doesn't download the new version of ckeditor).

I thought perhaps running composer civicrm:publish might invoke the magic, but that doesn't do anything either.

Anyone else managed to use composer to just update civicrm's ckeditor version?

p.s. okay, I tried reading the docs, here: https://github.com/civicrm/composer-downloads-plugin

It appears to say that it should update it if I've updated the composer.json and run composer install. I noticed that the composer.lock in the root hadn't changed it's version of ckeditor, so I updated that manually as well, but it had no effect.

Comment: According to @Demerit, composer won't do anything if you don't change the composer.json in the root of the project, so perhaps there a composer command to tell it to pay attention to the one I changed?

Comment: Yes, I could just update civicrm or yes, I could just manually replace the files as per the advisory. Where's the fun in that? But more importantly, I was hoping to automate it in an elegant way.

Comment: Regarding the docs for composer-downloads-plugin, it's true but again only if it's the root. If you want inelegant, what might work is to make your own copy of the civicrm-core repo somewhere where you change that composer.json, then in the root composer.json of the site you want to update you add a [vcs repo](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) definition for civicrm-core with a higher priority that points to your copy. Then composer will look there. I think I did that once to test something with a different repo, but don't remember how it worked out.